Get Hash from Biometric Fingerprint Data for Encryption
I'm trying to get a reliable hash from a fingerprint scanner to use as a encryption key. According to this post here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/103693/can-you-restore-a-private-key-from-biometrics, this can be done using stored error-correction data.
Is there a way to obtain this hash from the Adafruit Fingerprint Scanner Library for Arduino (ESP32 S2), i.e. grabbing the biometric data after the correction code has been applied to use as a reliable hash, that follows the three conditions outlined in the post above:


With error-correction data stored and made available independently of the biometric, we get the desired reproducible private key (or identifier).
The combination of said error-correction data and private key is non-revealing of the biometric.
Knowledge of both the biometric data and the error-correction data is needed to regenerate the private key, or match either the biometric data or the error-correction data with the private key.


If this is not possible using the Adafruit Scanner Library and/or the Adafruit scanner, what should I use in order to do this?

duplicate of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/97037/finding-data-from-adafruit-fingerprint-library-for-encryption-key

@jsotola my message before was asking if there is a general way to derive a key from a fingerprint, which I was told was not possible. I deleted that post because it wasn't specifically relevant to Arduino. In this post I am presenting a valid algorithm to derive a key from biometric fingerprint data, and asking for a specfic Arduino library/scanner (Arduino software & hardware) that has this capabilities. (Plus, the old message was deleted so it cannot be seen by others as a duplicate).
